# How to read file in docker container

Tags: spring, docker

I have a Spring application and I am running it inside docker with jenkins. I am moving a file from my system to the docker with:

```
docker cp foo.txt container_id:/foo.txt
```

But then I don't know how to read it:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("foo.txt")
```

Throws FileNotFoundException.

Normally I point to the folder like: C:/Users... But with docker how can I point to the root.

Comment: Have you tried `/foo.txt`? `/` is the root on all linux systems.

Comment: Also, I would recommend you to use spring utility:`org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils`. Try to do it with `File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("/foo.txt");` It works fine with `classpath:` files and also absolute paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`container_id:/foo.txt` means you copy file to `/` folder of container.

So, the correct way is:

```
new FileReader("/foo.txt")
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to copy files into docker.

You can create a volume

```
docker run -v your/host/folder:/your/container/folder ....
```

Then you can use it

```
Paths.get('/your/container/folder/foo.txt')
```